# IOS AWS Cognito Handlers not being called and wrong dataset value being returned

Tags: ios, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm having a two related issue.

Issue One: with getting the `Conflict Resolution Handler` and `Dataset Merge Handler` to work.  I've read the through [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/sync/handling-callbacks/) multiple times but I'm simply not seeing any success and the documentation is vague at best.  It appears the block handlers never seem to get called.

If I authentic through facebook, it takes my previous `Unauthenticated` identity and merges it into the facebook identity.  However, now I have two conflicting dataset entries showing for that facebook identity:

[image]

Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```
- (void)synchronizeCognito
{
    // Initialize the Cognito Sync client
    AWSCognito *syncClient = [AWSCognito defaultCognito];

    AWSCognitoDataset *dataset = [syncClient openOrCreateDataset:@"testing"];

    // Create a record in a dataset and synchronize with the server
    [dataset setString:identifier forKey:@"test1"];
    [dataset setString:token forKey:@"test2"];

    syncClient.conflictHandler = ^AWSCognitoResolvedConflict* (NSString *datasetName, AWSCognitoConflict *conflict) {
        NSLog(@"%@", dataset);
        // always choose local changes
        return [conflict resolveWithRemoteRecord];
    };

    dataset.conflictHandler = ^AWSCognitoResolvedConflict* (NSString *datasetName, AWSCognitoConflict *conflict) {
        // override and always choose remote changes
        return [conflict resolveWithRemoteRecord];
    };


    syncClient.datasetMergedHandler = ^(NSString *datasetName, NSArray *datasets) {
        // Blindly delete the datasets
        for (NSString *name in datasets) {
            AWSCognitoDataset *merged = [[AWSCognito defaultCognito] openOrCreateDataset:name];
            [merged clear];
            [merged synchronize];
        }
    };

    // synchronize the data
    [dataset synchronize];
}
```

Issue Two:
 Again, when I authenticate my `unauthenticated` identity with facebook and it merges the two.  I see: `identity changed from us-east-1:b0a5b4c4-8d7b-4564-9f92-5ea49bbfdcdc to us-east-1:f0bea5d1-a888-4f8f-8957-6589d9700c1e`

but if I do something like:

```
- (NSString *)getTest
{
    AWSCognitoDataset *dataset = [syncClient openOrCreateDataset:@"testing"];

    return [dataset stringForKey:@"test1"];
}
```

It return's test1 value data from the OLD identity's datastore instead of the new facebook identity's datastore even though they have now switched.  I suspect because no conflict or merge handling was called above.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the confusion. Your conflict handler will never be called in this scenario. Conflicts in Amazon Cognito only occur if both the local and remote data change in between a synchronization. Because you are changing data **and** merging an identity at the same time, the merge flow occurs.

When an identity merge is detected, the Amazon Cognito library does the following:

1. renames all local datasets to "NAME.old_identity_id"
2. calls the merge handler (if defined).

This means that if you made a change but did not synchronize, then logged in and caused an identity merge, the local change would never be propagated to the remote sync store unless you used the second flow from the [developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/sync/handling-callbacks/) and copied the data as necessary. I suspect this is what is causing your second issue.

As to your first, are you sure the merge handler is not being called? Can you add some debugging to your handler to see if it is actually being called?

Comment: Ah, this makes sense.  Ok, I'll revisit my flow and see if I can figure it out.  Thank you.  I may have more questions but we'll see.

Comment: Datasets have to be merged manually after identity change. So what the hell does Cognito do.. exactly?!